# Denoiser for Cubase 5?

Tags: noise-reduction, cubase, nuendo, software, plug-ins

Can I get a VST plugin of a denoiser for cubase 5? [Steinberg](http://www.steinberg.net/en/home.html) products like [Nuendo](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/audiopostproduction_product/nuendo4.html) and [Cubase](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/musicproduction/cubase5_product.html) are very similar, I would like to use [Cubase 5](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/musicproduction/cubase5_product.html) like I use [Neundo 3](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/audiopostproduction_product/nuendo4.html) for dialgoue editing and cleaning.

[Steinberg Cubase http://www.steinberg.net/index.php?eID=tx_nawsecuredl&u=0&file=uploads/pics/visual_products_cubase5_jhdregfhjegsh_82.jpg&t=1272817273&hash=d1967a4b1eb868e93e69162a3fa1491b](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/musicproduction/cubase5_product.html)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [iZotope RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/repair-and-edit/rx.html) ($349).

[image: iZotope RX]
<sub>(source: [izotope.com](http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/RX/images/denoiser_ss.jpg))</sub>

Comment: RX is good choice...

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom end of the scale you might want to try [Voxengo's Redunoise](https://www.voxengo.com/product/redunoise/) ($100), and at the top there is [Sonnox Restore] [$1900][5](http://www.sonnoxplugins.com/pub/plugins/products/restore.htm). Personally I would stick with [Nuendo] or purchase [Wavelab 7](http://www.sonnoxplugins.com/pub/plugins/products/restore.htm) when it is released later this year, as it will have the [Sonnox Restore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ2QZ.jpg) tools built in for about $700.

There are further excellent comments about noise removal software within the post "[How to clean a digitally distorted recording.](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/631/how-to-clean-a-digitally-distorted-recording)"

[image: Redunoise]
[image: Restore]
<sub>(source: [sonnoxplugins.com](http://www.sonnoxplugins.com/pub/plugins/images/restore-suite-600w.jpg))</sub>

Comment: great so you say wave lab? I was hoping cubase would have a denoiser (seeing as though it's steinberg) but ill checj it out thanks ian :D

Answer (score 1):

There's the [Waves Bundle](https://www.waves.com/plugins) with all its restoration tools that works great with Cubase and Nuendo (VST, Dx, RTAS)($1860).

[image: Waves Noise suppressor]
<sub>(source: [waves.com](http://www.waves.com/objects/images/large_screenshots/large_WNS.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

+1 for iZotope, excellent value for money, works as a plug-in or stand alone. See my review [here](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/jul08/articles/izotoperx.htm)

Hope that helps

Mike.