# Is there a way to increase WAV quality?

Tags: wav, sound-quality, tools

I have a WAV file with low quality. It cracks a little on some new Android devices. Is there a way (preferably a tool) to increase the quality of my file?

I was thinking about maybe an interpolation between the tones, so that the missing parts would be filled? I'm not sure if I understand correctly how this works.

Comment: Have you read [this post](http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/631/how-to-clean-a-digitally-distorted-recording/635#635) ? This might help you.

Comment: If it does crack only on some android devices but not on other systems, the issue might be related to the devices rather than the file. Possibly some peaks or transient.

Comment: If this only happens on some android devices then I would in fact suspect it has nothing to do with file quality as such, but with insufficient buffering for the uncompressed audio data. It's quite uncommon to use .wav with mobile devices so they may simply not be up to the high data rate, have you tried it with a low-loss compressed format (e.g. `.m4a` or `.flac`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the waveform does not peak at zero. In theory, you can normalize an audio waveform to zero and it is correct, but in practice, that will cause clipping in some playback situations. Clipping sounds like clicks or pops. It is common for experienced audio engineers to master an audio file so that the highest peak is at -0.3 dB. So if your file is normalized to zero, normalize it again to -0.3 dB.